# s3 javascript create bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have cognitoIdentityPool code for my credentials and use amazon aws javascript in browser. I can do everything with javascript in browser except createBucket. My js code in html is look like;

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
  Bucket: 'myuniquebucketname', 
  ACL: 'private',
  CreateBucketConfiguration: {
    LocationConstraint: 'us-east-1'
  },
  GrantFullControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantRead: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantReadACP: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantWrite: 'STRING_VALUE',
  GrantWriteACP: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

First of all, if I give full control, what can I write for STRING_VALUE in`GrantFullControl: 'STRING_VALUE',`
By the way, its not necessary to set up GrantRead, GrantWrite or other grant lines for working script. It gives cross origin CORS error. However I can delete bucket, upload file to buckets etc. clearly without CORS error. Any idea please.

Comment: I had no idea you can do that with JS, could you please tell me where to find tutorials to use JS on S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the expected behavior. Assuming that your page is served from mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com, then uploading a file via putObject results in an HTTP request to mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com (the same domain) and is therefore OK but calling createBucket targets s3.amazonaws.com (a different domain) and therefore results in a CORS error. Similarly, if you call listBuckets then it will fail with a CORS error for the same reason.

Comment: same domain, different domain or localhost.local domain doesnt matter. I can put file, delete bucket etc. from each domain. Just "createBucket" I cannot from any domain. My CORS configuration is ok.

Comment: @kaya_ What happens if you issue listBuckets?

Comment: Yes, when I call listBuckets, it fails with  CORS errors. But in sdk there is listBuckets property;
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listBuckets-property

Why?

Comment: S3 does support createBucket and listBuckets but you cannot invoke them from a browser. Both will fail with CORS 403 Forbidden. CORS is support on buckets, but does not appear to be supported on s3.amazonaws.com itself (I have no idea why that is). You need to find another solution to creating buckets.

Comment: I am facing the same issue :(

Comment: @mayank You'll need to find a different solution, for example using a REST call to an EC2 instance that can create the bucket for you. Also, the fact that you don't like the answer does not make it any less useful an answer.